# C++ generate 25 digit random number?

Tags: c++, random

How can I generate a 25 digit random number using `rand()` and store it as a string?

```
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    srand(time(0));

     char arr[26] = {0};

   for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++){

      arr[i] = rand() % 10+ '0';
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
     cout << arr[i] << " ";
   }

   return 0;
 }
```

This code generates 25 random numbers each time the program is run.

Similarly, I need to generate a 25 digit number and store it in an array.

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far and what the problem is.

Comment: i know how to generate 4-5 digit numbers. but not 25 numbers...

Comment: You do know the difference between [`std::srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) and [`std::rand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand)?

Comment: @AMZZ: this will suffer heavy downvoting until you tidy up the question (and could even result in your getting a question ban). Do you want a 25 digit random number? If so, when why do you mention "character array"?

Comment: Still unclear. Why is the title so different from the question text? Do you want a 25 digit random number or not?

Comment: Im really sorry ,question updated @Bathsheba

Comment: OK I've edited it the best I can. Two things though, 1) do you want a `std::string` or a `char[26]`. 2) Are you concerned about autocorrelation between any digits in the string? If you submit what you've done so far then folk will be sure to retract or even reverse their downvotes. Your question, fundamentally, is an interesting one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an array of twenty-six characters. In a loop from zero to twenty-four (inclusive) generate a random value between `'0'` and `'9'`, and add to the array. Terminate the array with the string terminator. Now you have a *string* with 25 random decimal digits.

---

For the actual random-number generation, I suggest you look into the new C++11 [random number functionality](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), especially [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Combine that with the [`std::generate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate) function from the [standard algorithm library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm), and you can do it with just a couple of lines.

Comment: Can you show the code of first method using rand() ?

Comment: @AMZZ It's basically what you have in in your question, but you have 26 digits instead of 25, and therefore overwrite the ending zero and don't have a string.

Comment: ok.. but the program generates **25 random numbers** not **25 digit random number**

Comment: @AMZZ But is each of those numbers one digit? Remember that you print a space between each digit for the output. Because the code, as show in your question, should print 25 random digits.

Answer (score 0):

This is the logic that i use,

```
int getRandom()
{
    const int size = 10;
    static int iBuff[10] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    static int iPivot = 0;

    if (iPivot >= size)
    {
        for(iPivot = 0; iPivot<size; iPivot++)
            iBuff[iPivot] = iPivot;

        iPivot = 0;
    }

    int iPos = rand()%(size-iPivot);

    int rand = iBuff[iPos+iPivot];

    //
    // swap values at iPos and iPivot
    //
    int temp = iBuff[iPivot];
    iBuff[iPivot] = iBuff[iPos+iPivot];
    iBuff[iPos+iPivot] = temp;

    iPivot++;
    return rand;
}


int main ()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
for (int iLoop=0; iLoop<25; iLoop++)
    cout<<getRandom()<<endl;

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's going to give you a very good distribution, but it may be good enough. Also, a little `const` would have killed you? ;)

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the logic? I'm struggling to see how this generates a 25-digit number; it looks more like it generates a random permutation of a set of 8 numbers, followed by undefined behaviour if you call it more than 8 times.

Comment: hmmm i was out for a while, @mike my bad, i did not read the question properly, i interpreted it as, you want to generate random numbers between 0-25... :p
and for the undefined behaviour if called more than 8 times, you can add a check at the begning,, 
if(iPivot >= SIZE_MAX) return -1;

Comment: @Hulk the code is corrected, the function can be called in loop and the output can be stored into the array, as asked in the question.
And about the bad practice and the error cases handling, i think it should be done by the person who is going to use the code, atleast i can expect that.

Comment: @mike minor changes were needed to handled the error and convert it form 8 to 25 digit random number.
I hope i do not need to tell small things like, a good seed value needs to be set to use rand function, i assumed it.

Comment: @51k  thanks.But your code shows no output and exits with code 8

Comment: @AMZZ see the edited code for main function, for how to use it,, in the for loop, use the returned value and append it in a string..

Comment: gives error : 'getRandom' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @amzz so declare it before using in the main function, possibly in your header file..

Comment: @51k downvote removed - the most serious issues have been solved.

Comment: @AMZZ: OK, as far as I can see, it probably does the right thing now (albeit not reentrant or thread-safe due to the pointless use of static variables, and insanely convoluted since `return rand()%10 + '0';` would do the same thing).

Answer (score 0):

srand only initialized the pseudo random number generator.

You might want to do something like this:

```
char array[26];
for(int x = 0; x < 26 ; x++)
    array[x] = rand()%10 + '0';

array[25] = '\0'
```

Comment: thanks. but it generates only 25 random numbers. I need to generate 25 digit number and store it in the array.